# How to resize my partitions?

Tags: high-sierra, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I have 3 partitions on my hard drive right now, and none of them are able to be resized (the apply button is greyed out when trying to partition).

I also feel like my drives are messed up in some way because I tried to get Apple support to help with resizing, and they just said they don't know what's going on, and I need to do a full reset. However, I don't want to reset the Bootcamp partition as I don't have access to/can't find the license anymore to reinstall Microsoft Office, which is mainly what I use Bootcamp for.

Can anyone help me figure out how to resize my OS X Base System or Bootcamp partitions, so that I can have more space on my MacOS Sierra partition?

Here are some details.

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            40.0 GB    disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                104.9 GB   disk0s4
   5:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         105.1 GB   disk0s5

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS OS X Base System       +39.7 GB    disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 D7973CD1-C28B-4D48-9D00-67E9F613D63D
                                 Unencrypted

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +105.1 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s5
   1:                APFS Volume MacOS Sierra            94.6 GB    disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 22.5 MB    disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                515.0 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk2s4

diskutil cs list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group A8032031-9A1E-439F-B836-4317DC3B4E1B
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         40028594176 B (40.0 GB)
    Free Space:   0 B (0 B)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 08D113CD-E0B8-43F6-BBDA-6CE28CD1992D
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     40028594176 B (40.0 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family D1D151BC-BDDE-4D3A-9997-0082983E4154
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         None
        |
        +-> Logical Volume D7973CD1-C28B-4D48-9D00-67E9F613D63D
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk1
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          39676272640 B (39.7 GB)
            Revertible:            Yes (no decryption required)
            LV Name:               OS X Base System
            Volume Name:           OS X Base System
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

[image: Overview]

[image: Storage Situation]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Disk Utility can't resize Windows NTFS partitions.
You can do advanced container/partitions editing in a GUI with a third party application:

[Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/hdm-mac/)

It has fully functional 10 day trial period.

Comment: Do you know what's going on with os x base system? Apparently, it's not supposed to exist be viewable?

Comment: I don't know what to do about OS X Base System. A better approach would be if you start from scratch. I know it's a lot of work, but with good planning you could have a better use of the storage. About that MS Office 2013/2016 License key - some websites state that you can't recover it, because only the 5 last characters are stored on your computer. However, other suggest that you can extract these last 5 characters with a VBScript code, and then matched with the rest of the key, stored in your Microsoft account page. It that's working, you can safely do a clean install.

Comment: [link](https://www.cocosenor.com/articles/product-key/check-and-view-office-2016-product-key.html) site